# kubelet failed with kubelet cgroup driver: "cgroupfs" is different from docker cgroup driver: "systemd"

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, kubeadm, kubelet

Configuration for `cgroup driver` is right in `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf`

```
Environment="KUBELET_CGROUP_ARGS=--cgroup-driver=systemd"
```

I also checked the `Environment` with cli

```
$ systemctl show --property=Environment kubelet | cat
Environment=KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS=--kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf\x20--require-kubeconfig=true KUBELET_SYSTEM_PODS_ARGS=--pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubernetes/manifests\x20--allow-privileged=true KUBELET_NETWORK_ARGS=--network-plugin=cni\x20--cni-conf-dir=/etc/cni/net.d\x20--cni-bin-dir=/opt/cni/bin KUBELET_DNS_ARGS=--cluster-dns=10.96.0.10\x20--cluster-domain=cluster.local KUBELET_AUTHZ_ARGS=--authorization-mode=Webhook\x20--client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt KUBELET_CADVISOR_ARGS=--cadvisor-port=0 KUBELET_CGROUP_ARGS=--cgroup-driver=systemd
```

> **`KUBELET_CGROUP_ARGS=--cgroup-driver=systemd`**

**How to reproduce it**:

- yum install -y docker-1.12.6
- systemctl enable docker && systemctl start docker
- setenforce 0
- yum install -y kubelet kubeadm
- systemctl enable kubelet && systemctl start kubelet
- systemctl daemon-reload
- systemctl restart kubelet
- kubelet log

**Environment**:

- Kubernetes version (use `kubectl version`): 1.7.3
- Cloud provider or hardware configuration**:   4 core 16G RAM
- OS (e.g. from /etc/os-release):  CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
- Kernel (e.g. `uname -a`): Linux 10-8-108-92 3.10.0-327.22.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jun 23 17:05:11 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Install tools: kubeadm

Answer (score 9):

On my environment it only worked the other way around. Setting systemd results always in an error. Here is my current setup

```
OS: CentOS 7.6.1810 
Minikube Version v1.0.0
Docker Version  18.06.2-ce
```

The solution for me was:
Check `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and change systemd to cgroupfs

```
{
  "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=cgroupfs"],
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "100m"
  },
  "storage-driver": "overlay2",
  "storage-opts": [
    "overlay2.override_kernel_check=true"
  ]
}
```

Then reload systemctl `systemctl daemon-reload`
Kill the previous minikub config `minikube delete`
and start the minikube again `minikube start --vm-driver=none`

Now check the command line the output should find  `cgroupfs` in both outputs

```
docker info | grep -i cgroup
cat /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf
```

In the end you should see

```
   kubectl is now configured to use "minikube"
=   Done! Thank you for using minikube!
```

**Simple solution:**
Start your minikube with the Extra config parameter

```
--extra-config=kubelet.cgroup-driver=systemd
```

The complete command to start up minikube is the next line

```
minikube start --vm-driver=none --extra-config=kubelet.cgroup-driver=systemd
```

All the best and have fun

Answer (score 7):

This is caused by miscofiguration during the initial startup. For example forgeting to change docker cgroup driver before executing `kubeadm init` command.

To remedy this under CentOS, open `/usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf` or locate the file under your operating system. Locate the entry with `EnvironmentFile=-/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env`. Open this file and change the value of `--cgroup-driver` to `systemd` or to be the same as docker cgroup driver.
Old Content:

```
KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS=--cgroup-driver=cgroupfs --network-plugin=cni --pod-infra-container-image=k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1
```

New Content:

```
KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS=--cgroup-driver=systemd --network-plugin=cni --pod-infra-container-image=k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1
```

Answer (score 7):

It may be better to do the reverse and make kubelet to use systemd

In Kubernetes site, they recommend using systemd 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/ 
More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60630294/429476)

And you can change kubelet to use systemd by following 
 https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/
adding this to  /etc/sysconfig/kubelet

---

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/kubelet 
KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--cgroup-driver=systemd
```

Comment: This is what finally worked for me. After hours of searching found this at the bottom of a stackoverflow answer that finally made things work.

Answer (score 6):

## Possible cause

[kubelet 1.7.3 not reading config file /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf #50748](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/50748)

## Solution

[Troubleshooting kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/troubleshooting-kubeadm/)

> If you are using CentOS and encounter difficulty while setting up the master node， verify that your Docker cgroup driver matches the kubelet config:

```
docker info | grep -i cgroup
cat /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf
```

> If the Docker cgroup driver and the kubelet config don’t match, change the kubelet config to match the Docker cgroup driver. The flag you need to change is --cgroup-driver. If it’s already set, you can update like so:

```
sed -i "s/cgroup-driver=systemd/cgroup-driver=cgroupfs/g /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf
```

This can be replaced with:

```
CG=$(sudo docker info 2>/dev/null | sed -n 's/Cgroup Driver: \(.*\)/\1/p')
sed -i "s/cgroup-driver=systemd/cgroup-driver=$CG/g" /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf
```

Answer (score 3):

To get minicube running on a CentOS 7, I need to start it with a `--extra-config=kubelet.cgroup-driver=systemd` as suggested in https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2192.

Comment: hi , thanks , it worked for me using minikube on rhel7.5

Answer (score 3):

I followed below steps in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Kubernetes v1.22.6 and latest version of Docker CE and Containerd.

I have changed the docker service file to change it to systemd. In the older version of kubeadm, kubectl and kubelet till 1.21.1 there was no problem.

And going forward docker service should use systemd by default.

Step 1: Stop docker service

```
    `systemctl stop docker`
```

Step 2: change on files /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/docker.service and /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service

Note: the file /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service is not avilable in my system.

From :

```
    `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock`
```

TO:

```
    `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock --exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=systemd`
```

Step 3: Start docker service and kubelet service

```
    `systemctl daemon-reload`
    `systemctl start docker`
```

Step 4: Since I had run kubeadm reset, I had to run kubeadm init. But it worked.

Step 0: Before all these, several commands need to run to enable containerd to use systemd.

> > cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/modules-load.d/containerd.conf overlay br_netfilter EOF
>
> sudo modprobe overlay
> sudo modprobe br_netfilter
>
> ## Setup required sysctl params, these persist across reboots.
>
> cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/99-kubernetes-cri.conf
> net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables  = 1
> net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
> net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1
> EOF
>
> ## Apply sysctl params without reboot
>
> sudo sysctl --system

[Kubernetes Container Runtime](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like kubelet process did not load the right settings from the `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf` telling from the error message.

After getting more info from the chat, I think there are several possible ways to go:

1. Switch both kubelet and docker cgroup driver to `cgroupfs`
   Download docker from the repo below which uses `cgroupfs` by default.

   ```
   [dockerrepo] 
   name=Docker Repository 
   baseurl=https://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/7 
   enabled=1 
   gpgcheck=1 
   gpgkey=https://yum.dockerproject.org/gpg
   ```

   And change the cgroup driver in kubelet conf as well. Check whether the error happens again and what kubelet loads from its conf.
2. Add more logs in kubelet code to debug it

   [This](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/4d409a4d9e9772193cb24944bd76b90aaca01473/pkg/kubelet/dockershim/docker_service.go#L221) is the logic kubelet uses to get conf from both sides

Comment: I don't think so, the error information is saying that the `cgroup-driver` of kubelet is already cgroupfs, which is diff from the docker.

Comment: @YuwenYan  What is your docker's cgroup driver ?  `sudo docker info | grep Cgroup`

Comment: I am asking cos by default docker 1.12.6 use cgroupfs in Centos 7.

Comment: it's `systemd`, I didn't changed it before, so I think the default config of docker is `systemd` too

Comment: It depends on which repo you used to download docker, I think. I am using the same environment as you do (same k8s version, same docker version, same OS). I downloaded docker from repo https://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/7 with cgroupfs pre-configured. I think it worth a try to change both settings to cgroupfs to locate the cause.

Comment: no, I just install it from the official repo, what's the diff?

Comment: and I think the problem is not about docker but kubelet, since the config of kubelet is right, but it just does NOT take affect.

Comment: @YuwenYan I am using the same kubelet version as you do got from the official repo but kubelet has no problem to load configs. So I guess if kubelet were the root cause, at least cgroup driver `cgroupfs` could be loaded without any problem.

Comment: Docker uses the cgroups driver, we need to update the kubelet to use cgroupfs.

Answer (score 2):

OS: Centos 7.4
As kubernetes 1.23.1 recommend to use cgroup `systemd`, and docker 20.10.20 use cgroup `cgroupfs`.
So, you have to change docker service file.

step1: Stop docker service

```
systemctl stop docker
```

step2: change on files `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/docker.service` and `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`

From :

```
`ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock`
```

TO:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock --exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=systemd
```

step3: start docker service and kubelet

```
systemctl start docker
kubeadm init phase kubelet-start
```

Answer (score 2):

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/configure-cgroup-driver/

Using the cgroupfs driver
As this guide explains using the cgroupfs driver with kubeadm is not recommended.

To continue using cgroupfs and to prevent kubeadm upgrade from modifying the KubeletConfiguration cgroup driver on existing setups, you must be explicit about its value. This applies to a case where you do not wish future versions of kubeadm to apply the systemd driver by default.

See the below section on "Modify the kubelet ConfigMap" for details on how to be explicit about the value.

If you wish to configure a container runtime to use the cgroupfs driver, you must refer to the documentation of the container runtime of your choice

Go to change config docker cgroupfs to systemd

edit:
/etc/docker/daemon.json

```
{
  "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"]
}
```

restart service docker

```
systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart docker && systemctl restart kubelet
```

show the config in

```
docker info |grep Cgroup
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit this file `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf` change **systemd** to **cgroupfs**". then restart the kubelet `systemctl restart kubelet`.

Answer (score 0):

Changing dockers cgroup driver as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65870152/4720757) answer worked for me.