# Unable to setup external etcd cluster in Kubernetes v1.15 using kubeadm

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes, high-availability, kubeadm, etcd

I'm trying to setup Kubernetes cluster with multi master and external etcd cluster. Followed these steps as described in [kubernetes.io](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/setup-ha-etcd-with-kubeadm/). I was able to create static manifest pod files in all the 3 hosts at /etc/kubernetes/manifests folder after executing Step 7.

After that when I executed command '**sudo kubeadmin init**', the initialization got failed because of kubelet errors. Also verified journalctl logs, the error says misconfiguration of cgroup driver which is similar to this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45708175/kubelet-failed-with-kubelet-cgroup-driver-cgroupfs-is-different-from-docker-c).

I tried as said in the above SO link but not able to resolve.

Please help me in resolving this issue.

For installation of docker, kubeadm, kubectl and kubelet, I followed kubernetes.io site only.

**Environment:**

Cloud: AWS

EC2 instance OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Docker version: 18.09.7

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching few links and doing few trails, I am able to resolve this issue.

As given in the Container runtime [setup](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/#docker), the Docker cgroup driver is systemd. But default cgroup driver of Kubelet is cgroupfs. So as Kubelet alone cannot identify cgroup driver automatically (as given in [kubernetes.io](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/kubelet-integration/#providing-instance-specific-configuration-details) docs), we have to provide cgroup-driver externally while running Kubelet like below:

> cat << EOF > /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/20-etcd-service-manager.conf
>
> [Service]
>
> ExecStart=
>
> ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet **--cgroup-driver=systemd** --address=127.0.0.1 --pod->manifest-path=/etc/kubernetes/manifests
>
> Restart=always
>
> EOF
>
> systemctl daemon-reload
>
> systemctl restart kubelet

Moreover, no need to run sudo kubeadm init, as we are providing --pod-manifest-path to Kubelet, it runs etcd as Static POD.

For debugging, logs of Kubelet can be checked using below command

> journalctl -u kubelet -r

Hope it helps. Thanks.