# I can't start Minikube

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, minikube

I have installed Minikube, but when I run `minikube start`, I get this error:

```
  minikube v1.17.1 on Ubuntu 20.04
✨  Using the docker driver based on existing profile
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Updating the running docker "minikube" container ...
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.20.2 on Docker 20.10.0 ...
  Unable to restart cluster, will reset it: apiserver healthz: apiserver process never appeared
    ▪ Generating certificates and keys ...
    ▪ Booting up control plane ...
  initialization failed, will try again: wait: /bin/bash -c "sudo env PATH=/var/lib/minikube/binaries/v1.20.2:$PATH kubeadm init --config /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml  --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube-etcd,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml,Port-10250,Swap,Mem,SystemVerification,FileContent--proc-sys-net-bridge-bridge-nf-call-iptables": Process exited with status 1
stdout:
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.20.2
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
[preflight] The system verification failed. Printing the output from the verification:
KERNEL_VERSION: 5.8.0-40-generic
DOCKER_VERSION: 20.10.0
OS: Linux
CGROUPS_CPU: enabled
CGROUPS_CPUACCT: enabled
CGROUPS_CPUSET: enabled
CGROUPS_DEVICES: enabled
CGROUPS_FREEZER: enabled
CGROUPS_MEMORY: enabled
CGROUPS_PIDS: enabled
CGROUPS_HUGETLB: enabled
[preflight] Pulling images required for setting up a Kubernetes cluster
[preflight] This might take a minute or two, depending on the speed of your internet connection
[preflight] You can also perform this action in beforehand using 'kubeadm config images pull'
[certs] Using certificateDir folder "/var/lib/minikube/certs"
[certs] Using existing ca certificate authority
[certs] Using existing apiserver certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing apiserver-kubelet-client certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing front-proxy-ca certificate authority
[certs] Using existing front-proxy-client certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing etcd/ca certificate authority
[certs] Using existing etcd/server certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing etcd/peer certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing etcd/healthcheck-client certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing apiserver-etcd-client certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using the existing "sa" key
[kubeconfig] Using kubeconfig folder "/etc/kubernetes"
[kubeconfig] Writing "admin.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "kubelet.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "controller-manager.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "scheduler.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env"
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
[kubelet-start] Starting the kubelet
[control-plane] Using manifest folder "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-apiserver"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-controller-manager"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-scheduler"
[etcd] Creating static Pod manifest for local etcd in "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[wait-control-plane] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests". This can take up to 4m0s
[kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.

    Unfortunately, an error has occurred:
        timed out waiting for the condition

    This error is likely caused by:
        - The kubelet is not running
        - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)

    If you are on a systemd-powered system, you can try to troubleshoot the error with the following commands:
        - 'systemctl status kubelet'
        - 'journalctl -xeu kubelet'

    Additionally, a control plane component may have crashed or exited when started by the container runtime.
    To troubleshoot, list all containers using your preferred container runtimes CLI.

    Here is one example how you may list all Kubernetes containers running in docker:
        - 'docker ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause'
        Once you have found the failing container, you can inspect its logs with:
        - 'docker logs CONTAINERID'


stderr:
    [
    ▪ Generating certificates and keys ...
    ▪ Booting up control plane ...

  Error starting cluster: wait: /bin/bash -c "sudo env PATH=/var/lib/minikube/binaries/v1.20.2:$PATH kubeadm init --config /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml  --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube-etcd,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml,Port-10250,Swap,Mem,SystemVerification,FileContent--proc-sys-net-bridge-bridge-nf-call-iptables": Process exited with status 1
stdout:
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.20.2
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
[preflight] The system verification failed. Printing the output from the verification:
KERNEL_VERSION: 5.8.0-40-generic
DOCKER_VERSION: 20.10.0
OS: Linux
CGROUPS_CPU: enabled
CGROUPS_CPUACCT: enabled
CGROUPS_CPUSET: enabled
CGROUPS_DEVICES: enabled
CGROUPS_FREEZER: enabled
CGROUPS_MEMORY: enabled
CGROUPS_PIDS: enabled
CGROUPS_HUGETLB: enabled
[preflight] Pulling images required for setting up a Kubernetes cluster
[preflight] This might take a minute or two, depending on the speed of your internet connection
[preflight] You can also perform this action in beforehand using 'kubeadm config images pull'
[certs] Using certificateDir folder "/var/lib/minikube/certs"
[certs] Using existing ca certificate authority
[certs] Using existing apiserver certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing apiserver-kubelet-client certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing front-proxy-ca certificate authority
[certs] Using existing front-proxy-client certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing etcd/ca certificate authority
[certs] Using existing etcd/server certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing etcd/peer certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing etcd/healthcheck-client certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing apiserver-etcd-client certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using the existing "sa" key
[kubeconfig] Using kubeconfig folder "/etc/kubernetes"
[kubeconfig] Writing "admin.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "kubelet.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "controller-manager.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "scheduler.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env"
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
[kubelet-start] Starting the kubelet
[control-plane] Using manifest folder "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-apiserver"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-controller-manager"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-scheduler"
[etcd] Creating static Pod manifest for local etcd in "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[wait-control-plane] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests". This can take up to 4m0s
[kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.

    Unfortunately, an error has occurred:
        timed out waiting for the condition

    This error is likely caused by:
        - The kubelet is not running
        - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)

    If you are on a systemd-powered system, you can try to troubleshoot the error with the following commands:
        - 'systemctl status kubelet'
        - 'journalctl -xeu kubelet'

    Additionally, a control plane component may have crashed or exited when started by the container runtime.
    To troubleshoot, list all containers using your preferred container runtimes CLI.

    Here is one example how you may list all Kubernetes containers running in docker:
        - 'docker ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause'
        Once you have found the failing container, you can inspect its logs with:
        - 'docker logs CONTAINERID'


stderr:


  minikube is exiting due to an error. If the above message is not useful, open an issue:
  https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose

❌  Exiting due to K8S_KUBELET_NOT_RUNNING: wait: /bin/bash -c "sudo env PATH=/var/lib/minikube/binaries/v1.20.2:$PATH kubeadm init --config /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml  --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube-etcd,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml,Port-10250,Swap,Mem,SystemVerification,FileContent--proc-sys-net-bridge-bridge-nf-call-iptables": Process exited with status 1
stdout:
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.20.2
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
[preflight] The system verification failed. Printing the output from the verification:
KERNEL_VERSION: 5.8.0-40-generic
DOCKER_VERSION: 20.10.0
OS: Linux
CGROUPS_CPU: enabled
CGROUPS_CPUACCT: enabled
CGROUPS_CPUSET: enabled
CGROUPS_DEVICES: enabled
CGROUPS_FREEZER: enabled
CGROUPS_MEMORY: enabled
CGROUPS_PIDS: enabled
CGROUPS_HUGETLB: enabled
[preflight] Pulling images required for setting up a Kubernetes cluster
[preflight] This might take a minute or two, depending on the speed of your internet connection
[preflight] You can also perform this action in beforehand using 'kubeadm config images pull'
[certs] Using certificateDir folder "/var/lib/minikube/certs"
[certs] Using existing ca certificate authority
[certs] Using existing apiserver certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing apiserver-kubelet-client certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing front-proxy-ca certificate authority
[certs] Using existing front-proxy-client certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing etcd/ca certificate authority
[certs] Using existing etcd/server certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing etcd/peer certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing etcd/healthcheck-client certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing apiserver-etcd-client certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using the existing "sa" key
[kubeconfig] Using kubeconfig folder "/etc/kubernetes"
[kubeconfig] Writing "admin.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "kubelet.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "controller-manager.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "scheduler.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env"
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
[kubelet-start] Starting the kubelet
[control-plane] Using manifest folder "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-apiserver"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-controller-manager"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-scheduler"
[etcd] Creating static Pod manifest for local etcd in "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[wait-control-plane] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests". This can take up to 4m0s
[kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.

    Unfortunately, an error has occurred:
        timed out waiting for the condition

    This error is likely caused by:
        - The kubelet is not running
        - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)

    If you are on a systemd-powered system, you can try to troubleshoot the error with the following commands:
        - 'systemctl status kubelet'
        - 'journalctl -xeu kubelet'

    Additionally, a control plane component may have crashed or exited when started by the container runtime.
    To troubleshoot, list all containers using your preferred container runtimes CLI.

    Here is one example how you may list all Kubernetes containers running in docker:
        - 'docker ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause'
        Once you have found the failing container, you can inspect its logs with:
        - 'docker logs CONTAINERID'


stderr:

  Suggestion: Check output of 'journalctl -xeu kubelet', try passing --extra-config=kubelet.cgroup-driver=systemd to minikube start
  Related issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/4172
```

I can't understand what the problem is here. It was working, but then I got a similar error. It says:

> Preparing Kubernetes v1.20.0 on Docker 20.10.0 ...| ❌  Unable to load cached images: loading cached images: stat /home/feiz-nouri/.minikube/cache/images/gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner_v4: no such file or directory

I uninstalled it and then reinstalled it, but I still got the error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you added the `minikube` binary to your `PATH`

Comment: Have exactly have you uninstalled the `minikube`? Is this issue reproducible after you run `$ minikube delete`? Have you tried to use different `minikube` version?

Comment: Did you try the solution provided [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52119985) because the error looks similar.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `minikube delete` to delete the old cluster. After that start Minikube using `minikube start`.

Answer (score 5):

I followed the below steps:

```
docker system prune

minikube delete

minikube start --container-runtime=containerd
```