# How to install Kubernetes Cluster on Azure Ubuntu Virtual Machine 20.04 LTS

Tags: azure, ubuntu, kubernetes, azure-virtual-machine

I’m working on to install the Kubernetes cluster on Azure Ubuntu Virtual Machine 20.04 LTS. For that I have followed below articles.

https://www.edureka.co/blog/install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu#InstallingKubeadmKubeletKubectl
https://adamtheautomator.com/install-kubernetes-ubuntu/#Initializing_a_Kubernetes_Cluster

Whenever I execute this `kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=<ip-address-of-kmaster-vm> --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16` cmd for initializing a Kubernetes Cluster on Master node, then  I’m getting the following error:

> [wait-control-plane] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests". This can take up to 4m0s
> [kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.
> [kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
> [kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.
> [kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
> [kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.
> [kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
> [kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.
> [kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
> [kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.

So, can anyone help me out for installing the Kubernetes Cluster on Azure Ubuntu Virtual Machine.

Comment: Please check this and see https://dev.to/adudko/setting-up-a-single-master-kubernetes-cluster-on-azure-using-kubeadm-1cjn. Here is the reference thread to fix the kublet errors https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52119985/kubeadm-init-shows-kubelet-isnt-running-or-healthy

Answer (score 4):

I have also faced this problem and solved this by changing the cgroup driver of docker to systemd

```
sudo vi /lib/systemd/system/docker.service

Then Modifiy the line as below

ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock --exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=systemd

sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
sudo systemctl restart kubelet
sudo systemctl status kubelet
```

If the kubelet status is active and running then you can apply the kubeadm join command and install kubernetes

Comment: This solved my issue, I was deploying on an _ec2_ instance running _Ubuntu-18.04_

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error many times and to be honest, it can be caused by many different things.

What helped me was to dig a little deeper into the logs of some of the Kubernetes components.

To view the status of the kubelet: `systemctl status kubelet`
To view the logs of the kubelet: `journalctl -exu kubelet`

Sometimes the problem can be with the pods that the kubelet is trying to start.

These can be debugged with the `crictl` tool which talks directly to the container runtime.