# Minikube not staring in linux machine

Tags: linux, kubernetes, minikube

Initially minikube used to run on the same machine.
Now when I am starting the minikube start command it is not starting tried everything but still the same.

Here are the logs of minikube start

```
[Company\sainath.reddy@hostm repos]$ minikube start
  minikube v1.26.0 on Amazon 2 (xen/amd64)
✨  Using the docker driver based on existing profile
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Pulling base image ...
  Updating the running docker "minikube" container ...
❗  This container is having trouble accessing https://k8s.gcr.io
  To pull new external images, you may need to configure a proxy: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/networking/proxy/
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.24.1 on Docker 20.10.17 ...
    ▪ kubelet.cgroup-driver=systemd
  Unable to restart cluster, will reset it: apiserver healthz: apiserver process never appeared
    ▪ Generating certificates and keys ...
    ▪ Booting up control plane ...
  initialization failed, will try again: wait: /bin/bash -c "sudo env PATH="/var/lib/minikube/binaries/v1.24.1:$PATH" kubeadm init --config /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml  --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube-etcd,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml,Port-10250,Swap,Mem,SystemVerification,FileContent--proc-sys-net-bridge-bridge-nf-call-iptables": Process exited with status 1
stdout:
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.24.1
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
[preflight] The system verification failed. Printing the output from the verification:
KERNEL_VERSION: 4.14.285-215.501.amzn2.x86_64
OS: Linux
CGROUPS_CPU: enabled
CGROUPS_CPUACCT: enabled
CGROUPS_CPUSET: enabled
CGROUPS_DEVICES: enabled
CGROUPS_FREEZER: enabled
CGROUPS_MEMORY: enabled
CGROUPS_PIDS: enabled
CGROUPS_HUGETLB: enabled
CGROUPS_BLKIO: enabled
[preflight] Pulling images required for setting up a Kubernetes cluster
[preflight] This might take a minute or two, depending on the speed of your internet connection
[preflight] You can also perform this action in beforehand using 'kubeadm config images pull'
[certs] Using certificateDir folder "/var/lib/minikube/certs"
[certs] Using existing ca certificate authority
[certs] Using existing apiserver certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing apiserver-kubelet-client certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing front-proxy-ca certificate authority
[certs] Using existing front-proxy-client certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing etcd/ca certificate authority
[certs] Using existing etcd/server certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing etcd/peer certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing etcd/healthcheck-client certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing apiserver-etcd-client certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using the existing "sa" key
[kubeconfig] Using kubeconfig folder "/etc/kubernetes"
[kubeconfig] Writing "admin.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "kubelet.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "controller-manager.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "scheduler.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env"
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
[kubelet-start] Starting the kubelet
[control-plane] Using manifest folder "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-apiserver"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-controller-manager"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-scheduler"
[etcd] Creating static Pod manifest for local etcd in "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[wait-control-plane] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests". This can take up to 4m0s
[kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.

Unfortunately, an error has occurred:
    timed out waiting for the condition

This error is likely caused by:
    - The kubelet is not running
    - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)

If you are on a systemd-powered system, you can try to troubleshoot the error with the following commands:
    - 'systemctl status kubelet'
    - 'journalctl -xeu kubelet'

Additionally, a control plane component may have crashed or exited when started by the container runtime.
To troubleshoot, list all containers using your preferred container runtimes CLI.
Here is one example how you may list all running Kubernetes containers by using crictl:
    - 'crictl --runtime-endpoint unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause'
    Once you have found the failing container, you can inspect its logs with:
    - 'crictl --runtime-endpoint unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock logs CONTAINERID'

stderr:
W0723 18:18:12.089975   49249 initconfiguration.go:120] Usage of CRI endpoints without URL scheme is deprecated and can cause kubelet errors in the future. Automatically prepending scheme "unix" to the "criSocket" with value "/var/run/cri-dockerd.sock". Please update your configuration!
    [WARNING FileContent--proc-sys-net-bridge-bridge-nf-call-iptables]: /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables does not exist
    [WARNING Swap]: swap is enabled; production deployments should disable swap unless testing the NodeSwap feature gate of the kubelet
    [WARNING SystemVerification]: failed to parse kernel config: unable to load kernel module: "configs", output: "modprobe: FATAL: Module configs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.14.285-215.501.amzn2.x86_64\n", err: exit status 1
    [WARNING Service-Kubelet]: kubelet service is not enabled, please run 'systemctl enable kubelet.service'
error execution phase wait-control-plane: couldn't initialize a Kubernetes cluster
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher

    ▪ Generating certificates and keys ...
    ▪ Booting up control plane ...

  Error starting cluster: wait: /bin/bash -c "sudo env PATH="/var/lib/minikube/binaries/v1.24.1:$PATH" kubeadm init --config /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml  --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube-etcd,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml,Port-10250,Swap,Mem,SystemVerification,FileContent--proc-sys-net-bridge-bridge-nf-call-iptables": Process exited with status 1
stdout:
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.24.1
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
[preflight] The system verification failed. Printing the output from the verification:
KERNEL_VERSION: 4.14.285-215.501.amzn2.x86_64
OS: Linux
CGROUPS_CPU: enabled
CGROUPS_CPUACCT: enabled
CGROUPS_CPUSET: enabled
CGROUPS_DEVICES: enabled
CGROUPS_FREEZER: enabled
CGROUPS_MEMORY: enabled
CGROUPS_PIDS: enabled
CGROUPS_HUGETLB: enabled
CGROUPS_BLKIO: enabled
[preflight] Pulling images required for setting up a Kubernetes cluster
[preflight] This might take a minute or two, depending on the speed of your internet connection
[preflight] You can also perform this action in beforehand using 'kubeadm config images pull'
[certs] Using certificateDir folder "/var/lib/minikube/certs"
[certs] Using existing ca certificate authority
[certs] Using existing apiserver certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing apiserver-kubelet-client certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing front-proxy-ca certificate authority
[certs] Using existing front-proxy-client certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing etcd/ca certificate authority
[certs] Using existing etcd/server certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing etcd/peer certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing etcd/healthcheck-client certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing apiserver-etcd-client certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using the existing "sa" key
[kubeconfig] Using kubeconfig folder "/etc/kubernetes"
[kubeconfig] Writing "admin.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "kubelet.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "controller-manager.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "scheduler.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env"
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
[kubelet-start] Starting the kubelet
[control-plane] Using manifest folder "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-apiserver"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-controller-manager"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-scheduler"
[etcd] Creating static Pod manifest for local etcd in "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[wait-control-plane] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests". This can take up to 4m0s
[kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.

Unfortunately, an error has occurred:
    timed out waiting for the condition

This error is likely caused by:
    - The kubelet is not running
    - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)

If you are on a systemd-powered system, you can try to troubleshoot the error with the following commands:
    - 'systemctl status kubelet'
    - 'journalctl -xeu kubelet'

Additionally, a control plane component may have crashed or exited when started by the container runtime.
To troubleshoot, list all containers using your preferred container runtimes CLI.
Here is one example how you may list all running Kubernetes containers by using crictl:
    - 'crictl --runtime-endpoint unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause'
    Once you have found the failing container, you can inspect its logs with:
    - 'crictl --runtime-endpoint unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock logs CONTAINERID'

stderr:
W0723 18:22:16.760474   50480 initconfiguration.go:120] Usage of CRI endpoints without URL scheme is deprecated and can cause kubelet errors in the future. Automatically prepending scheme "unix" to the "criSocket" with value "/var/run/cri-dockerd.sock". Please update your configuration!
    [WARNING FileContent--proc-sys-net-bridge-bridge-nf-call-iptables]: /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables does not exist
    [WARNING Swap]: swap is enabled; production deployments should disable swap unless testing the NodeSwap feature gate of the kubelet
    [WARNING SystemVerification]: failed to parse kernel config: unable to load kernel module: "configs", output: "modprobe: FATAL: Module configs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.14.285-215.501.amzn2.x86_64\n", err: exit status 1
    [WARNING Service-Kubelet]: kubelet service is not enabled, please run 'systemctl enable kubelet.service'
error execution phase wait-control-plane: couldn't initialize a Kubernetes cluster
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher


╭───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│                                                                                           │
│      If the above advice does not help, please let us know:                             │
│      https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose                           │
│                                                                                           │
│    Please run `minikube logs --file=logs.txt` and attach logs.txt to the GitHub issue.    │
│                                                                                           │
╰───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯

❌  Exiting due to K8S_KUBELET_NOT_RUNNING: wait: /bin/bash -c "sudo env PATH="/var/lib/minikube/binaries/v1.24.1:$PATH" kubeadm init --config /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml  --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube-etcd,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml,Port-10250,Swap,Mem,SystemVerification,FileContent--proc-sys-net-bridge-bridge-nf-call-iptables": Process exited with status 1
stdout:
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.24.1
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
[preflight] The system verification failed. Printing the output from the verification:
KERNEL_VERSION: 4.14.285-215.501.amzn2.x86_64
OS: Linux
CGROUPS_CPU: enabled
CGROUPS_CPUACCT: enabled
CGROUPS_CPUSET: enabled
CGROUPS_DEVICES: enabled
CGROUPS_FREEZER: enabled
CGROUPS_MEMORY: enabled
CGROUPS_PIDS: enabled
CGROUPS_HUGETLB: enabled
CGROUPS_BLKIO: enabled
[preflight] Pulling images required for setting up a Kubernetes cluster
[preflight] This might take a minute or two, depending on the speed of your internet connection
[preflight] You can also perform this action in beforehand using 'kubeadm config images pull'
[certs] Using certificateDir folder "/var/lib/minikube/certs"
[certs] Using existing ca certificate authority
[certs] Using existing apiserver certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing apiserver-kubelet-client certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing front-proxy-ca certificate authority
[certs] Using existing front-proxy-client certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing etcd/ca certificate authority
[certs] Using existing etcd/server certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing etcd/peer certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing etcd/healthcheck-client certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using existing apiserver-etcd-client certificate and key on disk
[certs] Using the existing "sa" key
[kubeconfig] Using kubeconfig folder "/etc/kubernetes"
[kubeconfig] Writing "admin.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "kubelet.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "controller-manager.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "scheduler.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env"
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
[kubelet-start] Starting the kubelet
[control-plane] Using manifest folder "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-apiserver"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-controller-manager"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-scheduler"
[etcd] Creating static Pod manifest for local etcd in "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[wait-control-plane] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests". This can take up to 4m0s
[kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.

Unfortunately, an error has occurred:
    timed out waiting for the condition

This error is likely caused by:
    - The kubelet is not running
    - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)

If you are on a systemd-powered system, you can try to troubleshoot the error with the following commands:
    - 'systemctl status kubelet'
    - 'journalctl -xeu kubelet'

Additionally, a control plane component may have crashed or exited when started by the container runtime.
To troubleshoot, list all containers using your preferred container runtimes CLI.
Here is one example how you may list all running Kubernetes containers by using crictl:
    - 'crictl --runtime-endpoint unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause'
    Once you have found the failing container, you can inspect its logs with:
    - 'crictl --runtime-endpoint unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock logs CONTAINERID'

stderr:
W0723 18:22:16.760474   50480 initconfiguration.go:120] Usage of CRI endpoints without URL scheme is deprecated and can cause kubelet errors in the future. Automatically prepending scheme "unix" to the "criSocket" with value "/var/run/cri-dockerd.sock". Please update your configuration!
    [WARNING FileContent--proc-sys-net-bridge-bridge-nf-call-iptables]: /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables does not exist
    [WARNING Swap]: swap is enabled; production deployments should disable swap unless testing the NodeSwap feature gate of the kubelet
    [WARNING SystemVerification]: failed to parse kernel config: unable to load kernel module: "configs", output: "modprobe: FATAL: Module configs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.14.285-215.501.amzn2.x86_64\n", err: exit status 1
    [WARNING Service-Kubelet]: kubelet service is not enabled, please run 'systemctl enable kubelet.service'
error execution phase wait-control-plane: couldn't initialize a Kubernetes cluster
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher

  Suggestion: Check output of 'journalctl -xeu kubelet', try passing --extra-config=kubelet.cgroup-driver=systemd to minikube start
  Related issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/4172

[Company\sainath.reddy@host repos]$
```

I have tried minikube start --extra-config=kubelet.cgroup-driver=systemd but still the same.
I am running the minikube on linux machine which is amazon linux 2

Here is the logs when I check kubelet service.

```
[Company\sainath.reddy@host ~]$ systemctl status kubelet.service
● kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
           └─10-kubeadm.conf
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-07-25 12:28:51 IST; 2s ago
     Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/
  Process: 744434 ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 744434 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
[Company\sainath.reddy@host ~]$
```

Comment: For me the issue was a wrong DNS settings in docker.daemon config

Answer (score 0):

Error message is, (you can search for this error keyword `K8S_KUBELET_NOT_RUNNING`):

```
[wait-control-plane] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests". This can take up to 4m0s
```

Kubelet has to be up for running. Check it with these:

```bash
systemctl status kubelet
journalctl -xeu kubelet
```

Steps:

0. Is systemd installed on your machine?

check it with this:

```bash
rpm -qa | grep -i systemd
```

else install with,

```bash
yum install -y /usr/bin/systemctl; systemctl --version
```

1. Try updating the cgroup driver in a [`/etc/docker/daemon.json`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file) file (create if it is not there!):

```json
{
    "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"]
}
```

2. Restart the services: (use `sudo` where needed)

```bash
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker.service
systemctl restart kubelet
```

After this if `kubelet` is running, then issue resolved.
And after this if you face issues with `swap`, you can swap off with [instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52196985/7860306).

Comment: `Sytemtemctl status kubelet `
Unit kubelet.service could not be found.

Comment: `kubelet.service` has to be there. Try restarting minikube. You should see whether it is `Running` and `enabled` state or otherwise.