# kubeadm init fails with error kubelet-config.yaml file missing

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to set up kubernetes cluster on centos 8 and running kubeadm init on the master and the error is that

> The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz'
> failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp
> [::1]:10248: connect: connection refused

I uninstalled kubeadm and docker and started from scratch again, but of no use
when i run  `journalctl -xeu kubelet`
the error is `no such file or directory, path: /var/lib/kubelet/kubelet-config.yaml`

I have been stuck with the error for a long time now, please help

tried this too , no luck - [kubeadm init shows kubelet isn't running or healthy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52119985/kubeadm-init-shows-kubelet-isnt-running-or-healthy)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the file is not being generated correctly during the Kubernetes initialization process.

You can try regenerating the **kubelet-config.yaml**

Run the following command:

```
sudo kubeadm init --config=/path/to/your/kubelet-config.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--var-lib-kubelet-kubelet-config.yaml
```

Verify the kubelet service `sudo systemctl status kubelet`

Or restart the kubelet service `sudo systemctl restart kubelet`

Since you have made multiple attempts to install Kubernetes, remnants from previous installations might be causing conflicts.

Try cleaning up the previous installation completely before attempting `kubeadm init` again. Use the following commands:

```
sudo kubeadm reset
sudo rm -rf /etc/kubernetes/
```