# Different version of docker engine with Openshift 3.11

Tags: docker, openshift

I have been working with docker version 18.02 building images locally. Now, I need to work with Openshift3.11 which run docker version 1.13. I just wondering if my images build locally be compatible and run in Openshift3.11.

More generally, what is the compatibility level/restrictions for images built by different version of docker engine? How to understand it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just wondering if my images build locally be compatible and run in
>   Openshift3.11

As I have been working for couple of years with Openshift, from 3.2 to 3.11, I can give some info on this

Here is the docker version that we use currently

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89
```

As stated by you **Openshift 3.11 needs [docker version with 1.13.1](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install/host_preparation.html#installing-docker)**, **but this won't stop you deploying images that were built with newer versions of docker**.

We were using Docker 18.*, earlier while deploying it to Openshift 3.2 and 3.9. **But haven't faced any issues so far with the compatibility of Docker images**.

For some **more info on docker compatibility** - https://success.docker.com/article/compatibility-matrix

If we check some of docker release notes/blogs we do see that **major changes were in either security/fixes/features or something more related to docker swarm**.

For example, from **[docker release 1.13](https://www.docker.com/blog/whats-new-in-docker-1-13/)**

> Benefits include:

```
Specifying the number of desired instances for each service
Rolling update policies
Service constraints
```

> Clean-up commands

```
Docker 1.13 introduces a couple of nifty commands to help users understand how much disk space Docker is using, and help remove unused data.

docker system df -- will show used space, similar to the unix tool df
docker system prune --  will remove all unused data.
```

Some more info on [release 1.13](https://docs.docker.com/release-notes/docker-engine/#1131-2017-02-08) and [release 1.19](https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/#19034)

So as a whole, **building images and running containers remain the same** irrespective of docker version we use, **if the underlying command/concepts are the same** in both the versions.

Hope this helps!

Comment: One thing should be added here: OKD 3.11 requires cgroup driver to be systemd. The default docker cgroup driver is cgroupfs. Need to apply `daemon.json` config to work https://stackoverflow.com/a/65870152/2689246